# schedule and cancel an unknown number of message sendings

Tags: scala, akka, scheduler

I want an `Actor` to be able to `scheduleOnce()` a message sending - any number of times - through message receipt (`receive()`). The `cancellable` thus created can be `cancel()`led through message receipt.

I encounter great difficulties to think about an architecture to handle this. Anyone'd have a clue on how to build this, with multiple `Actor`s, functions, etc...?

Can I just `cancel()` the *id* defined as follows?

```
class myActor extends Actor {
    def Receive = {
        case msg(t) => {
            createTrigger(t)
        }
        case _ => //do something
    }

    def createTrigger(t) => {
        val id/*cancellable*/ = context.system.scheduler.schedule(t milliseconds,
                                    someActor,
                                    someMessage)
    }

    def cancelSchedule(cancellable) => {
        cancellable.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Save all schedules in a ArrayBuffer and cancel when necessary. As a side note, dont create separate `ActorSystem` for this purpose. Use `context.system`

Comment: I edited my question with `context.system`. Isn't there an `akka` *ier* way to do what I want, or is your solution the only one?